# c# json merge child by key

Tags: c#, json, merge

txtOdds.txt:

```
{
 "events": [
   {
     "id":629087820,
     "awayScore":3.0, "homeScore":2.0,
     "awayRedCards":0.0, "homeRedCards":0.0,
     "periods":[
       {
         "lineId":330076348, "number":0, "cutoff":"08/22/2016 22:00:00",
         "maxSpread":12000.0, "maxTotal":12000.0,
         "spreads":[
           { "hdp":-0.25, "home":1.757, "away":2.19, "altLineId":null }
         ],
        "totals":[
          { "points":5.75, "over":1.74, "under":2.19, "altLineId":null }
        ],
        "maxMoneyline":4000.0,
        "maxTeamTotal":null,
        "moneyline":{"home":6.8,"away":1.699,"draw":3.06},
        "teamTotal":null
       }
     ],
     "starts":null, "home":null, "away":null,
     "rotNum":null, "liveStatus":0, "status":null,
     "parlayRestriction":0
   }
 ],
 "id":2196, "name":null, "homeTeamType":null,
 "hasOfferings":false, "container":null, "allowRoundRobins":false,
 "leagueSpecialsCount":0, "eventSpecialsCount":0, "eventCount":0
}
```

txtLeagues.txt

```
{
  "events":null,
  "id":2196, "name":"Spain - La Liga", "homeTeamType":"Team1",
  "hasOfferings":true, "container":"Spain", "allowRoundRobins":true,
  "leagueSpecialsCount":0, "eventSpecialsCount":0, "eventCount":11
}
```

I want to parse the odds.txt to object and then update league name by parse the txtLeagues.txt.

here is my code:

```
    JsonMergeSettings setting = new JsonMergeSettings();
    setting.MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Merge;

    string txtodds = txtOdds();
    var Odds = JObject.Parse(txtodds);
    var OddsObject = Odds.ToObject<PSLeague>();


    string txtleagues = txtLeagues();
    JObject Leagues = JObject.Parse(txtleagues);
    var LeaguesObject = Leagues.ToObject<PSLeague>();

    Odds.Merge(Leagues, setting);


    var test = Odds.ToObject<PSLeague>();
```

it is not working no matter I choose MergeArrayHandling to Concat or Replace or Merge or Union, any suggestions?

Comment: How are you expecting to merge? Always from one structure into the other? This way, you'll lose information. If one value is null then use the other? This way, how do you handle "eventCount" or "allowRoundRobins"? There is no sensible way to do this automtically: you will have to develop the merge logic yourself.

Comment: @PaulHicks I expect to replace all updated info every time when new data is coming.  It is working fine with eventCount or allowRoundRobins, they all replaced with the correct data, however it is not working when the object has a child. for example, initial object has no event, here comes a new object with 5 events, the result should be showing 5 events after merge. then 5 seconds later comes new object with 3 events, and the result should be showing 3 events. the object has primary key "id" for identify the object.